# ios8 Touch ID sensor is working but enter passcode in not working

Tags: iphone, ios8, touch-id

I am implementing Touch ID authorization in my application. It's working fine, but I also want to use the passcode option as an alternative to Touch ID, same as when the device is locked. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `evaluatePolicy` you get back `success: Bool` and `error: NSError!`.
if `error.code` is equal to `kLAErrorUserFallback` send the use to a specific Passcode screen you created yourself.

Comment: how to create passcode screen,If you have any demo or sample code link or code please give me thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just create a passcode screen like any other screen... 4 text fields, keyboard etc...

Comment: I did a small Google search. You can try and use this one - https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController

Comment: ok i have created and after that how to match to passcode to touch ID or password ??

Comment: The TouchID dialog is provided by the OS and it matches the user's system TouchID. The Passcode screen you will create CAN NOT match the user's system passcode automatically.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way how to use Apple's passcode mechanism/authorization. They've only made public the Touch ID API, thus allowing you to verify the user by a fingerprint.

You will have to provide your own implementation and the user will have to set up the password when first opening the app or somewhere inside the app (like settings).

You can check how it is done in 1Password app for iOS, which gives you a choice of using Touch ID or a passcode (that you have to specify when setting up the app).

**TL;DR** You have to do it yourself.